# How to lock / revoke access in database table from writing new data in It

Tags: mysql, sql, database, locking

How can I lock MySQL database table from writing data into it? I have game which insert score and user names to database, I need to lock It for now. That players can play, but result will be not written to database. My problem is that I can't edit files from FTP only database.

I've tried: `LOCK tables tableName WRITE;` but after this command used still data is writing to database. Is It possible to make that at all?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Read Lock:

```
LOCK tables tableName READ;
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but this wont help, I've tried It. As I understand I need to use revoke priv, but I don't know how to do It correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can [`revoke`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/revoke.html) the write privileges (insert, update, delete) from the relevant user.

Here's an example:

```
revoke insert,update,delete on your_schema.your_table from your_user;
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but i have few questions. what mean `your_schema`? This is my database's name? And what do you mean `your_user`? I need to revoke privileges from all users to 1 table?

Comment: your_schema represents the name of your database schema. If the database is named "game" and the table is named "score" then the command would be `revoke insert,update,delete on game.score from ...`

Comment: Privileges are managed at the user level, so you need to issue 1 revoke command for each user that you want to affect.

Comment: Thank you for answer, about `your_schema` I understand, but I misunderstood about users. In my table is only 2 columns userName and score without access. So how code should looks like for revoke access for all users on this table?

Comment: The user I refer to is a mysql user, not a user of your application. For example you can run this query to list all of the mysql users in your database: `select user,host from mysql.user;`

Comment: After I use this command `select user,host from mysql.user;` I got error: `#1142 - SELECT command denied to user 'my_db'@'email.hosting.com' for table 'user'`